# Fish bone stuck in my throat

Tags: medications, ear, bones, fish, throat

I ate fish at lunch yesterday, kinda felt something in my throat, i assumed it'd go away. Later i started feeling like something is definitely there. I tried looking for it using but couldn't see it. I tried eating bread with peanut butter, honey, salt water, dry rice, banana but nothing helped. The other stressful thing is that, i dont specifically know where its stuck, i cant feel the right place. I slept at night thinking I'd probably go away which was foolish of me. This morning, well i kinda feel like its in my ear like close to my ear. Is that possible? What should i do, any recommendations? Oh and someone said to try homeopathic medicine, does that work or sth?

Answer (score 2):

Homeopathy remedies have no physiological effect (http://www.howdoeshomeopathywork.com).

A homeopathic consultation along with the associated ritual of prescription etc may have a psychological or placebo effect.

As far as the fish bone goes, chances are what you’re feeling is a scratch with associated inflammation which will go away in a few days (the perfect situation for a homeopathic remedy to “work”- a self limiting condition), but the only way to know for sure is to have someone competent have a look.